# Import dropdown formfields value from Word table to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm working with password protected completed Word templates saved as .docx and I do not have the password.

I want to import all the formfield inputs into Excel. Importing text by indicating its position in the table works, but I cannot find a way to import the dropdown values. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub extractData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim fileName As Variant

fileName = Dir("C:\Users\...\*.docx")

While fileName <> ""
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
Set tbls = doc.Tables
Set sh = ActiveSheet
Dim FmFld As Word.FormField
wd.Visible = False

    lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        sh.Cells(lr, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text)
        sh.Cells(lr, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(1).Cells(2).Range.Text)
        sh.Cells(lr, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(2).Cells(1).Range.Text)
        sh.Cells(lr, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Text)
        sh.Cells(lr, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(3).Cells(1).Range.Text)
        sh.Cells(lr, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(4).Cells(1).Range.Text)
        sh.Cells(lr, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(6).Cells(2).DropDown.Value)
        sh.Cells(lr, 8).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tbls(1).Rows(6).Cells(3).Range.Text)
        sh.Cells(lr, 9).Value = doc.FormFields(15).DropDown.Value
       
        doc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        fileName = Dir()
Wend

wd.Quit
Set doc = Nothing
Set sh = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Sadly, it looks like the dropdown "bookmarks/names" don't exist. The first one seems to be the default "dropdown1" but then the others aren't named, likely due to being copy and pasted.

I was able to export the dropdown value using the index number but this changes from form to form depending on if people add more or less text and I can't check each form manually and count how many formfields there are until the first dropdown... Here is what worked in this example:

```
sh.Cells(lr, 7).Value = doc.FormFields(13).DropDown.Value
```

The table with formfields in the Word forms looks roughly like this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Q1: text input 1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Q2: text input 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Q3: text input 3</td>
    <td colspan="2">Q4: text input 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Q5: bullet point text inputs (approx. 5)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Q6: bullet point text inputs (approx. 5)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td><b>Q7: dropdown 1</b></td>
    <td>Q8: text input</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td><b>Q9: dropdown 2</b></td>
    <td>Q10: text input</td>
  </tr>
    
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: «I was able to export the dropdown value using the index number but this changes from form to form depending on if people add more or less text» If the documents have 'filling in forms' protection applied, how can people 'add more or less text' and what does this have to do with the formfield index numbers unless someone is changing the number of formfields, not just the amount of text in them?

Comment: That is a great question... and it turns out you're right. Some of the forms had the dropdowns deleted somehow (approx. 3 out of 100). No idea how they did that, but anyways, I dismissed the index solution just because of those few. INSTEAD, I just added "on error resume next" statements and it's working!

Should I mark this as solved or do you think there may be another solution out other than getting the index position of the dropdown?

Comment: «Should I mark this as solved» I'm not sure there's anything to mark. For a more efficient way to extract the data, see https://www.msofficeforums.com/59665-post2.html. The code there provides for the extraction of content control data too, but you can delete that part if you don't need/want it.